# Kendo Grid handling create/delete errors with popup editor

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid that does a create/delete, both of them ending with errors.
I would like to:.

1. When having an error on delete to prevent the row deleting from the grid (that is the default behavior when having errors)
2. When having a create error to prevent the popup editor to close

Please see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/andreigavrila/p49eV/2/

```js
var data = [
  { Id: 1, Name: "Decision 1", Code: 1 },
  { Id: 2, Name: "Decision 2", Code: 2 },
  { Id: 3, Name: "Decision 3", Code: 3 }
]; 

$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            error: function (a) {
                console.log('error');
                $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").cancelChanges();

                //$('#grid').data("kendoGrid").one("dataBinding", function (e) {
                   //e.preventDefault();   // cancel grid rebind
                //});
            },
            transport: {
                read: function(e) {                                
                  e.success({data: data});
                },
                create: function(e) { 
                  console.log('creating');
                  e.error();
                }, 
                destroy: function(e) { 
                  console.log('deleting')
                  e.error();
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "data",
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { type: "number" },
                        Code: { type: "number" },
                        Name: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        toolbar: ["create"],
        columns: [
            { field: "Code", title: "Code", },
            { field: "Name", title: "Name" },
            { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;" }],
        editable: {
            mode: "popup"
        }
    });
```

The second point works by default (so having an error on create does not close the popup)

The first point works by adding the error function, but that breaks the popup (it closes on error).

So I can have either one of my , but not both in the same time. I am kind of stuck.
I also saw this 2 questions on kendo forums:

- [delete error](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-complete-for-asp-net-mvc/grid/deleted-row-removed-from-grid-even-though-errors-returned-in-destroy-method.aspx)
- [server validation](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/mvvm/handling-validation-errors-from-server-in-kendo-grid.aspx)

The second link said "to prevent the Grid from closing you need to prevent the next dataBinding event." but i can't make that work.

Thank you for your help.

Andrei

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed to push this to Kendo forums:

Tthe official solution to that:
http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/kendo-grid-handling-create-delete-errors-with-popup-editor.aspx

> "I suggest you to use an if condition in the error event handler to
>   determine which of the two workarounds should be executed. In this
>   case the server should provide information about type of the error
>   that occurred. You can retrieve the error status from error event
>   arguments."